# Prevent function from being called directly

Tags: javascript, oop, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm building a wrapper for the HTML5 File(Reader) API with a fallback to normal file inputs or swfupload.

I have one general function "Uploader" and three sub functions (all in the same scope)

```
function Uploader() { }

function UploaderAPI() { }

function UploaderSWF() { }

function UploaderHTML() { }
```

The idea is that you create a `var uploader = new Uploader()` and that function calls one of the subfunctions, based on feature support/configuration.

However, I was wondering if there's a way to prevent users from directly calling one of the subfunctions, and instead have them only available to Uploader().

Is this doable without moving them to the Uploader scope?

Comment: The ordinary vars inside your function are private.

Comment: "Is this doable without moving them to the Uploader scope?" - no - the only way to make the functions only visible to Uploader is to move them into Uploader scope as the answers below do, this is the definition of scope.

Comment: @JamesGaunt - Yes it is possible. Look at my answer. I didn't move it to the `Uploader` scope. I moved all the functions into an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ "Ben Alman &raquo; Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)") which returns the `Uploader` function.

Comment: @Aadit - yes you have - you might be calling Uploader something different but essentially you're moving the private functions into the public function and the public function is Uploader.  You can wrap it in other things and change the name but it's the same solution.

Comment: @JamesGaunt - I beg to differ. The `Uploader` scope is the scope of the function called `Uploader`. The other functions are defined in it's parent scope (i.e. the scope of the IIFE). Thus the `Uploader` function is in fact a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science) "Closure (computer science) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia") who's upvalues are the other functions. It's not the same as the other functions being local to the scope of `Uploader`.

Comment: @Aadit - I see what you've done, but you've still created a function and put your private functions inside it. Only the code in this function can access the private functions.  You've then unnecessarily added some extra complexity by putting this code into another private function to create a closure and return this, but this is just moving the code deeper into what was the original Uploader scope.

Comment: @JamesGaunt - No. I haven't added any extra complexity. The reason I didn't move the other functions into `Uploader` is because they only need to be defined once. If I had moved them into the actual `Uploader` function then every time you call `Uploader` JavaScript would define the other functions again. This is additional overhead, and certainly more complex that what I did. I simply created a wrapper for already existing code.

Comment: @Aadit - I'm not saying your code is bad - it's probably what I'd do.  I'm just saying that it does move the private functions into what was originally considered Uploader scope.  The complexity is 'unnecessary' in that it doesn't change this fact.  At the end of the day if your contention is that these functions aren't in the scope of Uploader, and they aren't in some more 'global' scope, then how is Uploader calling them?  By 'original Uploader scope' I mean the original global function - which is the scope the OP referred to when asking the original question.

Comment: @JamesGaunt - Still don't believe that my method is better. Look at the JSPerf results: http://jsperf.com/closures-vs-redefining-code

Comment: Ok - the question is about scope, not performance.  You could make it even faster by inlining the private functions in the public function.  But that's not relevant to the question.

Comment: @JamesGaunt - I do stand by my words that in my program the additional functions are not in the `Uploader` scope. The are not local to the `Uploader` scope. The belong to the scope that's the parent of the `Uploader` scope. This is in contrast with the program written by @FabrizioCalderan in which the additional functions are local to the `Uploader` scope; and as my JSPerf link above proves - my method is faster because since the additional functions are not local they do not need to be redefined and hence the program executes MUCH faster.

Comment: You're just choosing to call Uploader something else. It's semantics. Uploader in the question is the global function, and your private functions are in this scope.  You could just as easily rename Uploader to Downloader and then the functions are no longer in Uploader scope.  Anyway - happy to disagree on this point.

Comment: @JamesGaunt - Nomenclature doesn't matter. The point is that the additional functions do not belong to `Uploader` or `Downloader` or whatever else you may wish to call it. They belong to the IIFE. Just because the IIFE returns `Uploader` (or whatever else you call it) and it's stored in a global variable called `Uploader` that doesn't mean the the additional functions belong to it. They still belong to the IIFE. They are still not local to `Uploader` or whatever else it is you wish to call it. The IIFE is not the same as the `Uploader`.

Comment: @JamesGaunt - BTW you haven't given me any substantial evidence (indeed you haven't given me any evidence at all) to prove that you are indeed correct. I have linked you to credible sources defining what's an IIFE and what's a closure. I have given you empirical evidence to show that the additional functions belong to the IIFE and not the `Uploader` (which is a closure). I've proven to you that my program is faster. All you have done is rant, proclaim and deny.

Comment: Ok, I was just having a discussion, as this is a programming discussion site. I didn't think it was ranting.  If I'd know you were getting upset I'd have left it. Apologies if I was. As I said I'm more than happy to disagree on this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) and define those functions as *private* methods (through closure) but this will move your functions inside another scope.

e.g.

```
var Uploader = function() {

   var UploaderAPI = function() { alert('uploaderAPI'); };

   var UploaderSWF = function() { alert('uploaderSWF');  };

   var UploaderHTML = function() {  alert('uploaderHTML'); };

   return {

      /* expose public methods here */

      publicMethodAPI : function() {
          alert('public uploaderAPI');
          UploaderAPI();
      }
   };
};
```

Doing so you can choose to make some public methods available along with an instance and use those function inside it, but without call them directly e.g.

```
var myupl = new Uploader();
myupl.publicMethodAPI();
```

Example (working) fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ndQFB/

Comment: Your code is wrong. `Uploader` in your case is an `object`, not a `function`.

Comment: Plus you wouldn't be able to call `publicMethodAPI` from an instance of `Uploader`. It's not defined on `Uploader.prototype`.

Comment: @AaditMShah my code works fine, is not wrong. Try it into you javascript console (and if you see some alert please consider to remove your downvote)

Comment: My mistake. However I won't remove my downvote. The OP wants to use `Uploader` as a constructor. By returning an object you're essentially breaking his code. Plus what you described is not the module pattern. In the module pattern you immediately invoke the function expression. That's what confused me. See your own link.

Comment: Check your own fiddle. `myupl` is not an instance of `MyUploader`: http://jsfiddle.net/ndQFB/1/

Comment: I feel this really is the approach I would like to take. However, I was wondering about one thing (not really clear at the moment): my Uploader function is going to need some callbacks. Is there a way to trigger callbacks from one of the private functions?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve with callbacks? anyway if you define a callback as a private method you can call it from public or private methods as in the example given

Comment: One of the callbacks will be `onFileSelect`: when you select a file, this one gets called, it has to return  true or false, depending on that, the file gets added to the list of files to upload. I want to expose it to the user, so he can easily validate files.

Comment: Could you have a look at following fiddle and just tell me if I have the right idea? http://jsfiddle.net/q9Pg2/

Comment: yes but i would rather create a public function `setCallback(name, function)` in which you can redefine a specific callback, instead of polluting the call to the constructor function